# DataGridView align one specific Cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, alignment, cell

Is it possible to align one single specified cell in c# dataGridView?

The idea would be something like this (but without errors)

```
tT.Rows[j][1].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight;
```

Comment: To the -1, doing such without reason I consider rude.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - DataTables hold only data. No formatting! You probably mean a DataGridView?  - Posting questions without any discernible research is considered rude. But I agree: the reason should be stated, at least for the 1st downvote, at least unless the post is  absolutley terrible. This is pretty bad but not  absolutley terrible.

Comment: Now I have the reason I agree and have made the required edit. I did mean dataGridView. A mix up is not directly rude I'd say but here we go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it possible to align one single specified cell in DataGridView?*

Yes, this is quite easy. **Either pick** the `Cell` and set the `Style`:

```
DataGridViewCell dc = dataGridView1[0, 0];   // short reference
dc.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

**Or code** the `CellPainting` event to **conditionally** align `Cells`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.RowIndex >= 0) && (e.ColumnIndex >= 0))
    {
        if (e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString() == "ddd")
        {
            e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight;
        }
    }
}
```

Coding suitable conditions is up to you, of course.

[image]

Note that after reloading the rows the alignment from the 1st option will be gone; the 2nd way will still align those cells that fit the conditions..

Comment: Thank you very much, I also appreciate you even give two possible ways of doing this